# How to set hubProxy signalr to a variable react-native?

Tags: react-native, signalr

is it possible to set a HubProxy to a variable and access its methods?
For example:

```
conectarChat()  {
    const connection = signalr.hubConnection(url);
    connection.logging = true;

    const proxy = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');

    this.proxy_signalr = proxy;

    // ... connection start and other stuff
}
componentDidMount() {
 this.conectarChat();

 this.proxy_signalr.on('msgRecebida', (id_enviou, id_recebeu, mensagem) => {
      //some function
 });
}
```

If the .on method is within conectarChat() function it works perfectly.

Thanks,
Bruno